# Problem on limits of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I came across this problem in real analysis by Titu Adreescu
 I am not able to understand the solution as  $\lim _{n \to \infty } log{b_{n}^{n}}=\infty$ then how  did they get the solution as $\frac{1}{e}$. Can someone please explain the solution or give an alternative solution to the problem.

[image: I came across this problem in real analysis by Titu Adreescu]

Comment: It would be clearer to  infer $b_n\to 1$ from (1.2). Then, presuming that $b_n=1+c_n \ne 1$ we have $(b_n-1)/\ln b_n=c_n/\ln (1+c_n)\to 1 
$ because $c_n\to 0.$ .....In (1,2) we have $(b_n)^n\to e.$ So  $b_n= (e(1+d_n))^{1/n}$ where $d_n\to 0$, so $b_n\to 1.$  And since $(b_n)^n\to e$ we have $\ln ((b_n)^n)\to \ln e=1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_n = \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}\frac{b_n - 1}{\ln b_n} \ln b_n^n$$

For the first term on the right,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt[n]{n!}}{n}=e^{-1}\tag{1}$$

For the second term, from L'hopital rule,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{b_n - 1}{\ln b_n}=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x-1}{\ln x}=\lim_{x \to 1} x = 1 \tag{2}$$

Also, we have 
\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty} b_n^n &= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(n+1)!}{n!}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}} \\
&=  \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n+1}{\sqrt[n+1]{(n+1)!}} \\
&=e\end{align}

Hence $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \ln b_n^n=1\tag{3}$$

To know the limit of $a_n$, you just have to multiply the $3$ terms up.

Comment: But  I am not able to understand why is the limit of ${b_{n}^{n}}$ found separately and not as $\lim _{n\to\infty }  log{b_{n}^{n}}$ please help

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \log b_n^n = \log( \lim_{n \to \infty} b_n^n)$ because logarithm is a continuous function.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt now I am able to understand  the solution

Answer (score 0):

The point is: $$\lim_{n\to {\infty} }\frac{b_n-1}{lnb_n} = 1$$
and $$\lim_{n\to {\infty} } {\ln{b_n}^n} = 1 $$ because $$\lim_{n\to {\infty} } {{b_n}^n} = e$$

therefore $$a_n = {1\over e} . 1 . 1 = {1\over e}$$